# repeat multiple NULL in R

Tags: r

In my simulation I need a vector that looks like:

```
vec = NULL NULL NULL NULL 2 2 2 2 4 4 4 4
```

However, in R when I use `rep(NULL, 4)` it returns nothing. For example,

```
vec.all = c(rep(NULL, 4), rep(2, 4), rep(4, 4))
vec.all
2 2 2 2 4 4 4 4
```

Is there a way to repeat `NULL` several times in R? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NULL` has no length:

```
> length(NULL)
[1] 0
```

So you can't really insert it into a vector. You can either have `NA` in you vectors or have a list with `NULL` items.

```
vec.all = c(rep(NA, 4), rep(2, 4), rep(4, 4))

list.all = c(rep(list(NULL), 4), rep(list(2), 4), rep(list(4), 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem toady and the accepted solution does not work for me. Here's how to create a list of length `n` with all elements `NULL` -

```
l <- vector(mode = 'list', length = 5); l
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
NULL
```