# Drop levels of a factor when droplevels() doesn't work in R

Tags: r, function, loops, subset

After subsetting variable `t` (which is a vector of `NULL`s) from my data.frame `D`, I get an object of class factor.

I use `droplevels` to drop the levels and get a vector of `NULL`s, I was wondering why I can't still achieve a vector of `NULL`s?

```
D <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/i/master/m.csv", h = T)

L <- split(D, D$study.name) ; L[[1]] <- NULL

t <- lapply(1:length(L), function(i) L[[i]]$t)

droplevels(t[[1]]) ## keep the vector of `NULL`s but drop the levels

## EXPECTED OUTPUT:
[[1]]
[1] NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
```

Comment: Please add expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, NULL objects are specifics like NA. This post is a really good explanation :

[repeat multiple NULL in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609887/repeat-multiple-null-in-r)

To create an empty vector with NULL value object, it is hard because it is a 0 length object, maybe you could use NA or use the other solution :

```
D <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/i/master/m.csv", h = T)
L <- split(D, D$study.name)
L[[1]] <- NULL # NULL is 0 length, you cancel the first element of your list.

t <- lapply(1:length(L), function(i) L[[i]]$t) # Your try

# 2 solutions :
t <- lapply(1:length(L), function(i) rep(NA, length(L[[i]]$t))) # Replace with NA
t <- lapply(1:length(L), function(i) rep(list(NULL), length(L[[i]]$t))) # Replace with list of NULL 
: the result is a list of list with NULL
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. but I tried a different strategy. But I really appreciate your response. Actually, I upvoted it.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe the reason why you can't have a vector of NULL is just coming from the fact that NULL is 0 length. So you can't create a vector of 4 length with 4 NULL because one NULL is 0 length. Thanks !